# Laravel return redirect in catch

Tags: laravel, redirect, transactions, try-catch

I'm trying to learn laravel and I have redirect problems in catch clause.
The following code catches the exception but not redirects me to / path
even when I comment dd($e).

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function() {
        model1->save();
        model2->save();
        ....
    });
    return redirect('/');
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    dd($e);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: and where does this code live?

Comment: where is this code? in some random function, in a controller? where ... need the context

Comment: @lagbox it is in a model

Comment: and what is calling this function in your model? you are just returning a value, what is then returning that value from this code?  more context

Comment: @lagbox I call this function from a controller in which I create a new instance of comment and then i call comment->insert() which runs the code above.

Comment: or     `return $thatmodel->insert();`  which would return the redirect response you are returning from that method   but probably better to not have the model being in control of the response ... good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

@lagbox thx for help I got it... I just connected your stuff with my useless coding skills and I found out how dumb I am :/ . Actualy it s too late for coding but nvm :). So the solution is: In Model:

```
    try{
        DB::transaction(function(){
           model1->save();   
           model2->save();                 
           ...
        });
        return true;
    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        //dd($e);
        return false;

    }
    Then in controller
    `
        if(!methodInModel){
            return 123;
        }
    `
```